# SwiftUI + Core Data: list doesn't refresh changes (no relationship)

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Recently I have integrated Core Data to my SwiftUI App.
Just to simplify, I have two views:

- TimerListView: fetch data from Core Data and show the list
- TimerDetailView: show Timer details and update data

  ```
    struct TimerListView: View {

   @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

   @FetchRequest(
       sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Timer.id, ascending: true)],
       animation: .default)
   private var timers: FetchedResults<Timer>

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView{
           List {
               ForEach(timers) { timer in
                   NavigationLink(destination: TimerDetailView(timer: timer)) {
                       TimerCardView(timer: timer)
                   }
               } 
           } 
       }
       [...]
   }
  ```

  }

Where

```
struct TimerDetailView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@ObservedObject var timer: Timer
```

Outcomes

- Data is correctly updated in Core Data (if I close and reopen the App data is correctly updated)
- When from TimerDetailView I turn back to TimerListView (after an update) the list doesn't show the updated data

Comment: just an observation, Swift has already a `class Timer`, it could be that you and the compiler will (eventually) get confused when `Timer` is used and you expect your Timer class `ObservableObject`

Comment: Yes, could be. If nobody else answer, I copy the project and try to change entity name.

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**: all child classes view have to define `Timer` attribute using `@ObservedObject` wrapper.
In previous code I replaced, into `TimerCardView(timer: timer)`:

- from `var timer: Timer`
- to `@ObservedObject var timer: Timer`

And now WORKS!